# WiFi connection lost. Reboot required

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, wifi

TLDR; It was a hardware issue.

MacBook Pro - Mid 2012

OS X Mavericks 10.9.3 (and the problem occurs with 10.9.2 as well)

I'm experiencing some severe WiFi issues. Every 20 minutes or so my Macbook loses its WiFi. This happens at several different locations.

When this happens it looks as if I'm still connected, but I'm not. The drop-down menu does not show any networks. If I turn off WiFi I'm unable to turn it back on again, with a few exceptions (though still no functionality). My guess is that when this happens I've already lost my WiFi completely, the computer just hasn't realized it yet.

The shell command `airport` shows the same behaviour as I'm seeing in the GUI. When I lose the connection, `-I` gives me `AirPort: Off`, and if I manage to turn it on, a scan finds nothing.

At the time of the problem, the Console doesn't contain anything relevant.

Rebooting the computer *always* fixes the issue, temporarily. I'm of course looking for a solution to the actual problem, but avoiding a reboot would be very helpful as well, especially since it might get me close to a solution. I've tried to restart the WiFi in various ways, but nothing but the reboot has any effect.

I found a thread on this subject:

[Is there an equivalent command for 'init.d/networking restart' in OS X](https://serverfault.com/q/140327)

but nothing there has worked.

Things I've tried:

- `ifconfig eth1 down/up`
- `networksetup -setairportpower en1 off/on`
- adding a new Location in the Network settings with no connection options (such as WiFi, Ethernet, Bluetooth, etc.) and switching to this Location and then back to the default
- switching both channels and frequency (40MHz -> 20MHz) on the router, even though I know it's not the router.

One theory is that the network card is starting to fail. If so, how would I determine this?

Any ideas?

Some technical info:

```
  Software Versions:
  CoreWLAN: 4.3.3 (433.48)
  CoreWLANKit:  3.3.2 (332.36)
  Menu Extra:   9.3.2 (932.35)
  System Information:   9.0 (900.8)
  IO80211 Family:   6.3 (630.35)
  Diagnostics:  3.0 (300.40)
  AirPort Utility:  6.3.2 (632.3)
  Interfaces:
en1:
  Card Type:    AirPort Extreme  (0x14E4, 0xF5)
  Firmware Version: Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
  MAC Address:  7c:d1:c3:84:85:c2
  Locale:   ETSI
  Country Code: SE
  Supported PHY Modes:  802.11 a/b/g/n
  Supported Channels:   1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 64, 100, 104, 108, 112, 116, 120, 124, 128, 132, 136, 140
  Wake On Wireless: Supported
  AirDrop:  Supported
  Status:   Connected
```

**Edit:**

New symptom:
Sometimes when I do `networksetup -setairportpower en1 on` the whole computer freezes.

**Edit2:**

I did a complete reinstall, with a partial time machine restoration (no network settings, among other things). Nothing's changed.

**Edit3:**

The problem seems to be related to temperature, which strongly indicates that there's something wrong with the network card. I'm going to replace it.

If you want to check for temperature issues, keep your computer on a cool surface and see if that helps.

Comment: you have done a lot, could you provide a Console report around the time stamp of the problem, maybe there is something in there.

Comment: And consider updating OS X.

Comment: I've updated OS X, and the log doesn't contain anything related to the issue at the time of the problem.

Comment: Please provide Console report to see who is turing off your Airport.

Comment: I checked it. It had no entries whatsoever concerning networking. The last time I checked was seconds after it occurred, and nothing had been logged for minutes. Is there some superuser log to check out?

Comment: I would say the card is headed out the window. Go to an AASP or Apple Store and let them test it.

Comment: I'd prefer testing it on my own. Do you (or anyone) have any tips on how to diagnose such an issue?

Comment: I just turned on monitoring in "Wireless Diagnostics". Not that I've ever gotten anything relevant from a built-in GUI diagnostics tool...

Comment: I had similar issues on Snow Leopard. There was some problem with OS X WPA implementation. If you have access to your AP you could change the settings to WEP and see if the problem disappears.  If it does try tweaking the WPA settings.

Comment: I too think it's the card going out; however, testing on a different network could be a good step before dissecting your MBP. Try starbucks or a neighbor to eliminate your router dropping you as a variable.

Comment: @RyanHollingsworth I did just that today, and updated the question to reflect this (it's not the router). I'm also leaning towards hardware now :/

Comment: BTW, how did you deduce that the problem is temperature related?

Comment: It wasn't much of a deduction actually :) But, I noticed that restarting didn't always help, and then I put it away for a while, and then it worked. I then realised that keeping the laptop in my lap was speeding up the process. Keeping it on a cool surface let me sustain internet for several hours (instead of 0-10 minutes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments and feedback, I'm going to go with your airport card is dying.

Assuming you do not wish to spend hundreds to repair it (I attempted to find a price chart on apple's support site but couldn't find any MBP prices) here's the do it yourself info you need.

The repair for this is pretty easy actually. Here's a link to iFixit's manual on how to get to the part you need to replace:
http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2012+AirPort-Bluetooth+Board+Replacement/10757

Here's the part you need:
http://www.ifixit.com/Store/Parts/MacBook-Pro-Unibody-Early-2011-Late-2011-Mid-2012-Airport-Bluetooth-Board/IF161-083-1

or on Amazon ( a little less expensive)

[http://www.amazon.com/Apple-MacBook-Unibody-Bluetooth-661-5867/dp/B00DDA5SK6/ref=pd_sim_sbs_misc_2/181-3489976-5928859?ie=UTF8&refRID=0P706PF5CMYQHHPRXHVQ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DDA5SK6)

Comment: I've actually opened up my macbook on several occasions and plan to replace it. Thank you very much for all the links, they can be hard to find! Also, I'm about to update my question with this: the problem is connected to temperature, so it's the card.

Comment: awesome, looks like a 15min job once you have the replacement part. best of luck and let me know if that was actually the problem :)

Comment: This was the problem. Unfortunately the connector cable was damaged as well

Answer (score 2):

You can try to connect without UI

Manually connect to WiFi

Turn On

```
networksetup -setairportpower en0 on
```

Find

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport scan
```

Connect

```
networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 WIFI_SSID_I_WANT_TO_JOIN WIFI_PASSWORD
```

If it works it is not the hardware. In that case the Console report would be helpful to find out who is turning your airport off. That is indicated by the fact that rebooting fixes it, so you have a app messing up your Airport.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I edited my post to reflect that this works as with the GUI, i.e. not at all.

Answer (score 1):

Thoughts to (hopefully) narrow down the problem:

- It sounds like this is happening regardless of whether your macbook
  is plugged in/charging or running off battery power. Is this
  assumption correct?
- In System Preferences, under Energy Saver, is Wake for Ethernet Access enabled?

Try turning off various services, then reenable one at a time to see if anything changes:
 - turn off bluetooth, Airdrop, any file or network sharing, and wake on ethernet access (I know we're talking about wireless, but since both wireless and ethernet fall under networking let's just disable it for now).
 - reboot after turning these off, and each time you reenable one of them.

I know this will take up a lot of time, and I'm sorry about that. It is definitely how I would continue to troubleshoot my own.

Comment: Yes, your first assumption is correct, battery power/charging makes no difference. Wake for network access is currently enabled. I'm in the process of trying your suggestion. Thanks for the input!